# Installing RMARIADB on CentOS 7.5

Tags: c++, r

I have been trying to install RMariaDB on my CentOS server with no success.  I am running R version 3.5.  I keep getting error messages related to scope.  The source files seem to be correct and the install has been MD5 Sum checked.  The package will unpack but then fails with a non-zero exit status. I get similar error messages whether I am installing RMySQL or RMariaDB.  They are both related to the my_bool variable.  Specific error messages are posted below:

```
> install.packages("RMariaDB")
Installing package into ‘/home/cmiddlet@cgifederal.com/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMariaDB_1.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 42903 bytes (41 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 41 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RMariaDB’ ...
** package ‘RMariaDB’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using mysql_config
Found mysql_config/mariadb_config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql -m64 
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
** libs
g++ -m64  -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -m64  -I"/usr/share/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/share/R/library/plogr/include" -I"/home/cmiddlet@cgifederal.com/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c DbConnection.cpp -o DbConnection.o
g++ -m64  -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -m64  -I"/usr/share/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/share/R/library/plogr/include" -I"/home/cmiddlet@cgifederal.com/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c DbResult.cpp -o DbResult.o
In file included from MariaResultPrep.h:6:0,
                 from DbResult.cpp:4:
MariaBinding.h:14:15: error: ‘my_bool’ was not declared in this scope
   std::vector<my_bool> is_null;
               ^
MariaBinding.h:14:22: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<my_bool> is_null;
                      ^
MariaBinding.h:14:22: error: template argument 2 is invalid
In file included from MariaResultPrep.h:9:0,
                 from DbResult.cpp:4:
MariaRow.h:18:15: error: ‘my_bool’ was not declared in this scope
   std::vector<my_bool> nulls_, errors_;
               ^
MariaRow.h:18:22: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<my_bool> nulls_, errors_;
                      ^
MariaRow.h:18:22: error: template argument 2 is invalid
make: *** [DbResult.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMariaDB’
* removing ‘/home/cmiddlet@cgifederal.com/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RMariaDB’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMariaDB’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpwlaf35/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Are there any errors prior to this? Can you post the full output of the attempted installation?

Comment: Which development packages are you using for MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: I have mysql-community-devel-8.0.11 installed.  Attempting to install any other development package generates a message such as this:

Package 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-devel-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do

Comment: The installation instructions at https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/blob/master/README.md list other packages as dependencies. I cannot test that, though.

Comment: As an update, I never could get RMariaDB to install on my system running MySQL .  Because I had a fresh install of MySQL with no data associated with it, I decided to uninstall MySQL and install MariaDB instead.  This may not be the ideal situation for everyone but it worked for me.  Here's how I did it (as root):
-yum remove 'MySQL*'   #yum will look for everything on your system preceeded by MySQL and ask if you want to remove it
-yum clean all   #this will clear the cache
-yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client MariaDB-devel MariaDB-shared #this will install everything for Maria DB

Comment: I was then able to switch back over to RStudio and install RMariaDB successfully

Comment: So the solution was to uninstall MySQL?